# How does the RadTreeView know that an item node is a droppable folder

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, radtreeview

I have a "simple" RadTreeView. The ItemsSource of my HierarchicalDataTemplate is SubItems.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" ...
```

Drag and Drop seems to work. But I am wondering how the RadTreeView knows that my item is a droppable folder. It seems that if SubItems is null it is NOT a droppable folder. Is it true? Is it the right way to mark an item as "folder" or "file"?

Answer (score 0):

In the way of data binding you mark an item as "folder or file" by the data model behind that binding.

For example with a property.

```
public bool IsFolder { ... }
```

This can also be used for the control to evaluate if drag and drop is enabled for the appropriate item. But as the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreeview/features/drag-and-drop.html) states this seems to be done in code behind.

For switching the template you can use a customized [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I hope I understood your question in the correct way :D